# ASP.NET Core 7 IResults usage

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

Please I'd like to know why I can't use the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults`, but I can use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Results` namespace has the `Results` class which gives us different `IResult` implementations.

I noticed the constructors for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults` aren't in the doc. Are they private constructors? Please a dices explanation on this will help.

I have tried using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults` but keeps saying classes constructors have 0 parameters

Comment: isnt [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresults?view=aspnetcore-8.0) a namespace that contains a lot of `IResult` implementations?

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults` is a **namespace** - not a **class** - and a namespace cannot have any constructors - only classes (and structs) do ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults` is a namespace which contains classes that implement the IResult interface, so it will not contain any constructors.

The IResult interface defines a contract that represents the result of an HTTP endpoint.

The static Results(`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Results`) class is used to create varying IResult objects that represent different types of responses.